# HTML Email - Server Username visible as the sender

Tags: php, email, html-email, web-hosting

I have a website where whenever a order is placed, an email is sent to the customer as well as the admin.

Now the emails are sent to both the customer and Admin, but the header where i specify the email for the addresser does not work. When the email arrives the addresser email is displayed as my username used to login to the Server.

I managed to get the addresser email to work only when the email is NOT formatted with HTML.

I used HTML to format the emails and I use 'mail()' function to send it. 
eg.

I have the same code for Admin email but with different variables..

```php
  $toCustomer = "customerEmail@gmail.com";
  $customerSubject = "Order Confirmation";
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\b";
  $headers .= 'From: automatedMesage@PleaseDoNotReply' . "\r\n";

  $customerTxt =" Order has been placed!!";

  mail($toCustomer,$customerSubject,$customerTxt,$headers);
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Sorry, Thought it to be relevant since it uses Server username. Not to sure how to get it removed

Comment: Pretty sure you need `from` formatted properly. Check it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php